# Plain Unstrucutred HTML Content Types, How to Pull image from them in Views

Tags: views, nodes, media

This is a plain unstructured node with no CCK structure or anything like that (the site includes thousands of posts so it is impossible to retroactively go back and re-insert the images in using CCK).

How can I pull the first image in the node out and use that image within a view as a thumbnail image? (It's a related posts view)

I'm not 100% sure how to create a view theme, the drupal documentation on it is really confusing and I can't find a good tutorial on how to create a custom view theme either.  So since I think that is the best solution if you know how to do that, could you point me to a tutorial or something that actually teaches you how to create your own themed view (one that makes sense).

Thanks for any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to only create one view theme. That will be a theme for the BODY field of your node. It's actually super simple.

- create a PHP file in your theme folder called views-view-field--YOURVIEWNAME--body.tpl.php
- your file has one variable you need to worry about, $output and that's the HTML. Write your PHP code to isolate the very first image tag and then [this site has a nice example of how to do that](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it)

I think the code in this file would end up looking like this

```
  $first_img = '';
  $numMatches = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $output, $matches);
  if($numMatches){
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
  }else{ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  echo '<img src="' . $first_img . '" alt="thumbnail" class="thumb"/>';
```

- add some CSS to make the thumbnail, or alternatively you can use theme with imagecache I think.
- refresh your template cache

You're done!